# Angular httpBackend: No pending request to flush

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I am trying to use the `$httpBackend` for testing my `AngularJS` application. However, it keeps telling me that I have no pending requests.

This is the test:

```
it('should attempt to get boards from server', function() {
    httpBackend.when('GET', rootScope.serverRoot + '/boards').respond({id: 1});

    var boards;
    BoardServiceInstance.getBoards().then(function(data) {
        boards = data;
    });

    httpBackend.flush();

})
```

And the service:

```
this.getBoards = function() {
    return $http.get($rootScope.serverRoot + '/boards');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks good to me.  Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ETsC5/) that seems to work.  Maybe see if you can spot any differences between the fiddle and the rest of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `$rootScope.$digest();` did the trick.

Here's the final code:

```
it('should attempt to get boards from server', function() {
    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/boards').respond({id: 1});

    var boards;
    mockBoardService.getBoards().then(function(data) {
        boards = data;
    });

    $rootScope.$digest();

    $httpBackend.flush();

})
```